# dynamic schedule graphic with backend interface

Tags: php, mysql, xml, flash, web-applications

Thinking about developing a "class schedule app" that has a backend user interface that a user can add/edit/delete dates and times, savs and the data shows in a cool graph on a webpage.

I was thinking of using authiticated php page to update an xml file or database that could be read by a flash app to create a dynamic graphic. Think a 800 x 500 square with the 7 days set as rows ontop of each other and the times for each day listed horizontally. The times set in xml/database would be color coded boxes with rounded corners that lay over the times for those days.

**I am not looking for anyone to tell me how to do this. I was hoping to get ideas or thoughts from other developers on my options as far as languages to dev in. I have done a few searches and found a lot of javascript calendars to select dates but I am less concerned about the backend looking good.

I am open to any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: You should read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reinvent the bicycle it probably easier will be to setup google apps for a student group [here](http://www.google.com/a/help/intl/en/edu/index.html#utm_campaign=generic_EDU&utm_source=en-print-na-us-generic_EDU&utm_medium=print), create a calendar, emails, docs, and all that stuff in one hour.

In case if you want to reinvent the bicycle, you can look at [these](http://www.queness.com/post/656/10-beautiful-jquery-and-mootool-calendar-plugins) jQuery based calendars ([quick demo](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html))

And back to your question, in my opinion mysql>>php>>xml>>flash/javaScript will work perfect for this kind of projects.